# Create/run command file programmatically

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm trying to create a cmd file that will install a .msi and then execute that cmd file via C# code. The code works perfectly if I run it using f5 or control + f5 from visual studio.

However, once I package up the code in a .msi file and install it (it's a wpf app), when it executes the relevant code, it opens the command window but it doesn't execute the command. Instead it says: "C:\Program is not recognized as an internal or external command..." I know this error means that there aren't quotes around a file path but that's not the case, as you can see below the quotes are there. Also, if I go to the program files directory, the Reinstall.cmd file is present and has quotes in it. I can even double click the generated  Reinstall.cmd file and it will execute just fine. What am I missing here??

Here is the code:

```
private string MSIFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "HoustersCrawler.msi");
        private string CmdFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Reinstall.cmd");

private void CreateCmdFile()
        {
            //check if file exists.
            if (File.Exists(CmdFilePath))
                File.Delete(CmdFilePath);
            //create new file.
            var fi = new FileInfo(CmdFilePath);
            var fileStream = fi.Create();
            fileStream.Close();
            //write commands to file.
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(CmdFilePath))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(String.Format("msiexec /i \"{0}\"", MSIFilePath));// /quiet
            }
        }

        private void RunCmdFile()
        {//run command file to reinstall app.
            var p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/k " + CmdFilePath);
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> as you can see below the quotes are there.

You put them in the first portion, but not where you're executing `cmd.exe`.

Since your path has spaces in it, you need to wrap it in quotes.  Try:

```
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/k \"" + CmdFilePath + "\"");
```