# GUI interface for mono terminal application OSX

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I have a terminal application written in C# which I run with mono. 
Now, I would like to write a GUI for this application. How can I use buttons to pass commands to this application, and how can I receive output from the terminal window?

Is there any possible way to do this? and if, **how**?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible, but if you have the source code for the application, you would be much better off incorporating that source code into your new application and providing a GUI directly rather than trying to work with the command interface.

Comment: I have the source code of the application, but it runs in command line mode in mono since the gui elements it uses are not all compatible with mono. I do not want to write a seperate gui in the application either since i get an ugly windows 95 looking window which mono uses to run the executables. I know this is possible, but i'm looking for the answer **how** to do this.

Comment: You could perhaps use the exe file as a reference  (it is just an assembly) If it has public classes you can call them from your gui program.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply to competent_tech what you want to do is create the GUI using [MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac).

> MonoMac, a new foundation for building Cocoa applications on OSX using Mono. 
>   MonoMac is the result of years of experimentation in blending .NET with Objective-C and is inspired by the same design principles that we used for MonoTouch. 
>   You can use MonoMac to publish applications to the Mac AppStore, to learn about this see the MonoMacPackager page.

What you are describing as a windows 95 looking window, is [winforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) which is the native .Net API for building GUI applications. With MonoMac you will be able to build a GUI application that uses your current applications source code and looks and feels just like a normal Mac application.

Again trying to call commands on your application is not an ideal way to go about this.

Comment: Thank you very much! i am gonna use this :D. Still i need to know how i can pass commands to a terminal application since this is not the only thing i came by to try this. Is there any way i can receive and send input to a terminal application?

Comment: You may want to try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910954/create-run-command-file-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If you have a command line program that you cannot modify then you probably want to invoke it directly [as a subprocess and capture it's text output](http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput).

You can then write whatever GUI you like (MonoMac/GTK#) to drive the app directly.